# Android and Java: Error in declaring R.id.Edit Text

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Eclips show error at editText1 when i write **ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);** although i declare it in layout and also add layout to android **Menifest file**.

```
`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
(1)setContentView(R.layout.app_info);

(2)ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
(   
}
```

`
i am getting error at the numbring lines.

here is my Xml File "app_info.xml"
    `

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="Patient Name">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Here is my complet Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="Patient Name">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="Contact No"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="Age"/>
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="Address"/>
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="BirthDay"/>
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10"/>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
        android:background="@drawable/dsdss"
        android:text="  " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Clean your project and check.

Comment: also save your appinfo.xml...:)

Comment: @Hardy i have clean my project many times but still getting same error.

Comment: @morroko appinfo.xml is save already...

Comment: Put your full code of appinfo.xml

Comment: @WaqasMarwat make sure you don't have `import android.R;`

Comment: can you past error here

Comment: @WaqasMarwat yes please check you are not import android.R.

Comment: Nothing wrong into xml code.. As Hardy said it much possible that you imported android.R... check import.

Comment: @Tarsem yes checked, well i remove the import.R and it solved for me. Thanks all of u.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:id="@+id/editText1"
```

In your layout file change the default editText1,editText2  to something else like input1,input2 or anything else other than editText1,editText2

**Don't use default id created by xml like editText1,button1**

Now run the code :)

Comment: I also want to know about this. Can you explain more ?

Comment: actuall this is the default id used by android. To use default id  we need to call findViewById(android.R.id.button1)

Comment: My Problem is solve already. it was just because of Import.R statement .

Comment: @WaqasMarwat congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

first restart eclise then go to xml file and make some changes and save it. Then clean your project. and then check your class, be sure not to

import android.R;

then again clean your project. 
Sometimes eclipse create problem, does not recognize xml file and its content. So there is no problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this and it was resolved by just selecting the option project>Build all option. If the Build automatically option is selected then remove it.

Comment: If still not resolved then write import <projectname>.R  For example import com.SimpleApp.R;